# How to make a class to manage tokens for other classes requesting from an api?

Tags: python

I am attempting to handle multiple classes requests to an API, although I am rate limited to ~30 requests/second/token and i have roughly 20 tokens. Needing to make ~30 million+ requests this could prove to take forever!

In my code right now, I just have a list of 4-5 tokens per class. And I'm looping through my request's and using the next token in that list.

```py
from ratelimit import limits
que = Queue()
tokens = ('t', 'o', 'k', 'e', 'n', 's')
urls = ['list', 'of', 'urls']

@limits(calls=30, period=1)
def get_api(url, token):
    #request info from api
    #then store in mongodb

def worker():
    while True:
        t = que.get()
        get_api(t[0], t[1])
        que.task_done()

for i in range(len(tokens)):
   t = Thread(target=worker)
   t.start()

for i, u in enumerate(urls):
        que.put((u, tokens[i%len(tokens)))
```

This is across multiple classes. I'd prefer to just have all classes share the same `queue` of tokens sort of speak.. I considered making a class that handles this  with a queue, although how can I ensure it uses each token only once before cycling through the tokens again.

Essentially. I'm trying to create a class that handles requesting the API, then returning the results, but I need this class to be accessible by multiple classes.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. But the `Queue()` is FIFO, so if you get token using `t=q.get()`, you are sure that nobody else uses this token until you return that token using `q.put(t)`. This should ensure that each token is used only once. So make queue for tokens.

Comment: The queue is for ratelimiting the requests made. I am limiting the number of requests by 30*number of tokens. My apologies, I'll edit and include that.

Comment: I've been doing some digging, found that a singleton may be my answer. I just need to read up more on it.